# Open GWT-Application in Headless Chrome doesn't work

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I'm currently working on an utility tool which is supposed to test a GWT-Application.
I want to use headless Chrome but it doesn't work

I do the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/"), cap);

    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

If I go to `google.com` with `driver.get(url)` and take a screenshot I can see the Google-Page, but as soon as I try to open the GWT app I only get a white page and the following source printed with `System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Secure Login Service</title>
</head>
<body>
```

But as soon as I remove the headless flag chrome starts and the gwt app loads normally

I'm running

- Chrome-Version 63.0.3239.84
- selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3
- chromedriver 2.33
- Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit

I cannot update Chrome, but I can try different versions of selenium-driver and chromedriver (I tried other versions but they wouldn't run - but that's another topic) - Is there another good headless-Browser which needs no installation (i.e. awesomeHeadlessBrowser.jar?)

I appreciate any help

Comment: OS? Can you share the concerned `url`?

Comment: @DebanjanB running windows 7 enterprise 64bit, i add this to the question, sadly I cannot share the url of the gwt application because its only available through the intranet of the company

Comment: I am still not sure why you want to invoke `driver.getPageSource()` within a Grid environment. `driver.getPageSource()` isn't a valid usecase for Grid rather it's used for debugging purpose. Whats your exact usecase?

Comment: @DebanjanB I don't wanna USE `getPageSource()` I only used it for debugging because I was wondering why something else isn't working, thats how I discovered that the Headless Chrome doesn't load the gwt app properly

Comment: Fundamentally, if without using _headless flag_ chrome starts, chrome should also start with _headless flag_. The `--disable-gpu` option @CoreyGoldberg suggested should give you a relif. But I will be much more interested in a concrete _usecase_ where you intend to interact with a _WebElement_ and face any such issue.

Comment: @DebanjanB  `--disable-gpu` doesn't make a difference - headless chrome starts and for example I can interact with WebElements on Google.com but it wont load the gwt app

Comment: I am suspecting in similar lines. Watchout if `<body>` tag have certain classes/attributes which detects _ChromeDriver_ (rather _OSS_ protocols) as a webcrawlers.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `--headless` option, you also need to pass it `--disable-gpu`.

However, instead of passing these options explicitly, just call `driver.set_headless()` (which will take care of setting both for you).

Comment: Amazing input @CoreyGoldberg as in `driver.set_headless()`